# How to add focus state to links within textview

Tags: android, focus, d-pad

I have a Eula dialog that contains a textview where I addLinks so that the links are recognized within the text string.  I am using dpad navigation and need the links to highlight if the focus is on them.  Is there a way to add a state to the links onFocus?  Can I direct focus to the positive and negative buttons too?  Here is the method:

```
 public static boolean show(final Activity activity) {
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        if (!preferences.getBoolean(ACCUWX.Preferences.PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED, false)) {
         final TextView message = new TextView(activity);
         final SpannableString s = preferences.getString(ACCUWX.Preferences.PREF_PARTNER_CODE, null).equals(ACCUWX.PartnerCodes.TMOBILE_PARTNER_CODE) 
            || preferences.getString(ACCUWX.Preferences.PREF_PARTNER_CODE, null).equals(ACCUWX.PartnerCodes.TMOBILE_7_PARTNER_CODE)?
                 new SpannableString(activity.getText(R.string.eula_terms_info_tmobile))
                    : new SpannableString(activity.getText(R.string.eula_terms_info));
         Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
         message.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
         message.setText(s);
         message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            if (ad == null) {
                ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle(R.string.terms_conditions)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.agree, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        accept(preferences);
                        if (activity instanceof OnEulaAgreedTo) {
                            ((OnEulaAgreedTo) activity).onEulaAgreedTo();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        refuse(activity);
                    }
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        refuse(activity);
                    }
                })

                .setView(message)
                .create();

                ad.show();
            }

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I can't figure out how to add a state to links that are within txt and not a separate view of their own.

*****EDIT*****
If I add this line of code:   message.setLinkTextColor(R.color.link_text);
then my links are not visible.  But this tells me it is at least recognizing the links.  Here is the ColorStateList applied (link_text.xml) stored in res/color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff33ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use OnFocusChangeListener, so:

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
mTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // Add your code for the focus change of the textview

    }

});
```

Comment: but how do I only add states for the links, not all of the text in textview?

Comment: I did the above with some success. My problem now is that I have 3 links in one textview...how do I separate know which one I have focus on? In the onFocusChange method I do if(hasFocus) message.setLinkTextColor(Color.MAGENTA); and if not message.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE);  What this does is change all the links colors as soon as I come off the "I agree" button into the textview.  I want to show when I am on each separate link.

Comment: I think the solution for you is to created three separate textviews if you don't want all three links highlighted at once and you don't want the same action associated with them.

Comment: I did exactly that...3 separate txt views.  Thank you